# Eclipse CDT cannot launch the binary it generated, but launch works from cmd

Tags: eclipse, opencv, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I am using eclipse juno, and using windows pe parser and mingw compiler. I am not using cygwin. I can build a binary successfully from eclipse, but cannot launch it. It fails with some null pointer exception.

I get the following error on eclipse.

"OpenCV Error: Null pointer (Invalid classifier cascade) in cvHaarDetectObjectsForROC, file C:\opencv210\opencv\sources\modules\objdetect\src\haar.cpp, line 1514

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
"
I run the same binary from cmd,  it executes fine without any error. Can someone give any pointers please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your xml-cascade file was not found.

also, please avoid using opencv's deprecated c-api. use a [cv::CascadeClassifier](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html) in the 1st place, and check CascadeClassifier.empty()

btw, i'd urge you to update from opencv2.1 to opencv2.4.9 . 2.1 is totally outdated, and should no more be used.

Comment: I have xml cascade in the same directory. I am able to launch the binary from cmd and it works! but only when i ask eclipse to launch, i see that error.

Comment: I am using opencv 2.4.1. I was trying to build some available code.